# XML seriazlizing byte[][]

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

how to serialize byte[][] to XML?

i got something like this in result:

```
<Data1>
    <base64Binary>YR1PEKAAAANDEAL</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>YRJPEKAAAACHEAT</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>YRJPEKAAAACHEAL</base64Binary>
```

but i like to got my each data array as HEX:

```
<Data1>
    <base64Binary>1202030405060708</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>1202030405060708</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>1202030405060708</base64Binary>
```

Comment: Please show the code that produced this XML. You should replace `base64Binary` with `hexBinary`.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, sorry. just need to add [XmlElement(DataType = "hexBinary")] to my Data field:

```
        [XmlElement(DataType = "hexBinary")]
    public byte[][] Data1
    {
        get { return Data; }
        set { Data = value; }
    }
```